# Retry in RestService doesn't work after Springboot update

Tags: java, spring

We lately updated our SpringBootVersion to 2.5.4 and Gradle to 7.2. Since then our retry code doesn't work anymore. see also https://i.ibb.co/1Tw7Nsg/retry1.jpg.

```
public class RestService {

    private final LoggingPropertyWriter loggingPropertyWriter;
    private final WebClient webClient;
    //private Retry exponentialRetrySpecification;

    public RestService(LoggingPropertyWriter loggingPropertyWriter,
                       WebClient webClient,
                       long firstBackoffMs,
                       long maxBackoffMs,
                       long maxRetryIterations) {

        this.loggingPropertyWriter = loggingPropertyWriter;
        this.webClient = webClient;
        this.exponentialRetrySpecification =
                Retry.anyOf(PacmanHttpResponseRetryException.class)
                .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(firstBackoffMs), Duration.ofMillis(maxBackoffMs))
                .retryMax(maxRetryIterations)
                .doOnRetry((
                        objectRetryContext -> {
                            log.info(() -> LoggingContentCreator.logHttpRetry(
                                    objectRetryContext.iteration(),
                                    objectRetryContext.exception().getMessage(),
                                    ((PacmanHttpResponseRetryException) objectRetryContext.exception()).getErrorCategory(),
                                    ((PacmanHttpResponseRetryException) objectRetryContext.exception()).getResponse()
                                )
                            );
                        }
                ));
    }
```

I am not able to use the method anyOf() (or other methods which could maybe help like retryWhen()). see also https://i.ibb.co/jvJ005y/retry2.png.

I only found this documentation (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/retry/Retry.html), which doesn't help me a lot.

Did anybody faced a similar issue or has a good description how I can implement the retry again?

Thanks and best regards,
Philip

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please don't post code as images, or worse links to images. Just post code as code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the picture (I am not allowed to add them directly) so that it is easier to see which part is marked red. Now I added the code as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a thought, but have you read the migration notes for the versions between your original Spring Boot version and the version you have upgraded to?  It might suggest why the methods/features you are using are no longer working the way you believe they should.